# How would you auto generate a class implementation during pre-compile?

Tags: c++, build

I was looking at creating a service locator that I would also like to provide "NULL" implementations of the services it provides.  How would you go about parsing the Interface and auto generating an implementation?  What tools would you use - say with CMake?  Basically, I am trying to avoid having to write something like:

```
class IAudio
{
    virtual void playSound(SoundId Id) = 0;
    ....
};

***** Following is the boilerplate I would like to avoid  *****

class NullAudio : IAudio
{
     void playSound(SoundId) override { /* Does Nothing */ }
     ....
};
```

I can't seem to find any examples from my google searches for automatic code generation - they all turn up things that reference code completion in editors.  I would even consider running a python script that looks for files starting with I - like IAudio.hpp, parses it and writes out a file if that is the common way to do this.

Thanks!

Comment: Ok - so why the downvotes?  I tried researching all the places I knew to look - like I said - I kept getting articles and questions about code completion in IDEs.  What isn't clear about the question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I figured it out.  Write a small tool to do what I want, configure CMake to compile it first, and then have CMake run the tool with add_custom_command.